# select certain field in relasionship table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to select some field in 3 differents table I don't know if I have to use a Query builer ( I prefer to avoid it ) or maybe I have made a mistake on my model

Here is my query code

```
$lobbies = Lobby::with(array('games' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id','name');
}))
->with(array('users' => function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'pseudo');
}))
->get();

return response()->json($lobbies);
```

It returns this:

```
[
   {
      "id":2,
      "description":"mon premier lobby",
      "created_at":"2020-05-13 12:02:36",
      "support_link":"https:\/\/discord.gg\/K3NGfv4",
      "nb_player":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "game_id":2,
      "games":{
         "name":"Counter-strike"
      },
      "users":{
         "id":1,
         "pseudo":"misakilou"
      }
   }
]
```

But I only need the description , the name (games names ) , the nb_player ,  and the pseudo not the others fields

Here is my differents models

UserModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'pseudo', 'mail', 'password','active','confirm_password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function lobbies(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Lobby');
    }

    public function getUsernameAttribute(){
        return $this->pseudo;
    }
}
```

GameModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'games';
    protected $visible = [
        'game_id','name', 'picture'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'picture'
    ];
    /*
    public function users(){
        return $this->HasMany('App\User');
    }
    */
    public function lobbies(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Lobby');
    }


}
```

And the LobbyModel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lobby extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lobbies';
    public $timestamps = false;
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'created_at', 'nb_player' ,'support_link', 'user_id', 'game_id'
    ];

    public function games(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Game', 'game_id');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `select` to the `Lobby` model, but keep in mind that you must select the foreign keys in order for the `with` to work. If you don't want that data to be included in the response, you can map the collection returned by the query to customize it before the return response. Something like this:

```
$lobbies = Lobby::select('id', 'description', 'nb_player', 'game_id', 'user_id')
->with(array('games' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id','name');
}))
->with(array('users' => function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'pseudo');
}))
->get();

$response = $lobbies->map(function ($lobby, $key) {
    $item = [
        'description' => $lobby->description,
        'nb_player' => $lobby->nb_player,
        'game_name' => $lobby->games->name,
        'user_pseudo' => $lobby->users->pseudo,
    ];
    return $item;
});

return response()->json($response);
```

If you want to avoid subsequent mapping on the collection, you can use joins instead of Eloquent's relationships. Something like this:

```
$lobbies = Lobby::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'lobbies.user_id')
            ->join('games', 'games.id', '=', 'lobbies.game_id')
            ->select('lobbies.description', 'lobbies.nb_player', 'users.pseudo', 'games.name')
            ->get();

return response()->json($lobbies);
```

Comment: Using join will have better performance in the query to DB and also avoid the later mapping. I kept the eloquent relationships option only to follow the same line of what you had been doing.